# How to check adjacent cell in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am developing a journey planner using python. I have been given an excel file containing a list of stations, their connected stations and the travel times between them.

I need to extract data from an excel spreadsheet and use it to implement a graph data structure, for which I am using an adjacency list.

[image: Excel Data]

As you can see in the image attached above, the data sheet is structured in the following way:

- The B column consists of all stations
- If a station is in column C, they are connected to the station in column B
- Column D is an integer representation of the distance between the connected stations

I have iterated over every station in column B and added them as nodes to my adjacency list in python. I have also developed a function named add_edge which takes arguments: node1, node2 and weight, then adds them to the adjacency list appropriately.

So now I need to figure out of way of translating this data to my function. My thinking is to develop a loop with the following structure:

- LOOP over all cells in column B (where the current iteration is node1) and check if the adjacent cell is empty.
- IF the adjacent cell in column C contains data (a connected station) add this to a variable (node2) THEN check the adjacent cell in column D and add this to a variable (weight)

From there I can plug the variables to my add_edge function.

If anyone has any idea how I would code this loop, or has a better solution, I would immensely appreciate it.

**TL;DR**
How can I check adjacent cells and store them as variable using pandas in python.

```py
class Graph:
    def __init__(self, nodes): 
        self.adj_list={}
        self.nodes=nodes

        #add nodes to adj_list
        self.adj_list = {node: set() for node in self.nodes}
            

    #Function which adds edges between nodes
    def add_edge(self, node1, node2, weight=1):
        self.adj_list[node1].add((node2,weight))

    #prints graph in readable format
    def print_graph(self):
        for node in self.nodes:
            print(node, ":", self.adj_list[node])
```

```py
df = pd.read_excel(r'myfile.xlsx',usecols="B")
nodes = set(df.iloc[:,0])

g = Graph(nodes)
```

Comment: Don't do it a column at a time, just iterate over the rows.  Then you can look at the three related columns as a unit.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your comment. Would you mind providing an example in code?

Comment: What code do you have?  You should show us, so we know where you're starting from.

Comment: Don't `usecols="B"`.  Grab the entire sheet.  Then, you can do `for row in df.iterrows():` and deal with one row at a time.